# Simplify $L_{-1}(x) + I_1(x) $

Tags: calculus, functions, special-functions, bessel-functions

Is there a simple solution for x << 0 of the following equation:

$$Y(x) = L_{-1}(x) + I_1(x) $$

Where $L_{-1}(x)$ is modified Struve function and $I_1(x)$ is modified bessel function.
For example we can see that despite the absolute values of 2 functions are very large they cancel each other:

$$L_{-1}(-25.5) = 9...e9 $$
$$I_{1}(-25.5) = -9...e9 $$
$$I_{1}(-25.5)+L_{-1}(-25.5) = 1e-3 $$

Comment: Asking Mathematica for a series expansion gives $$Y(x)=\dfrac{2}{\pi}x^{-2}\left( 1 + 3 x^{-2} + 45 x^{-4} + 1575 x^{-6}\right)+O(x^{-10})$$ for $x\ll 0$. As a numerical check, note that $\pi/2\approx 0.64$ and $Y(-10)\approx 0.0066=0.66\cdot10^{-2}$

Comment: Many thanks for the help